# Vee-Validation v4 serverside error message on ErrorMessage tag

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vee-validate, nuxt3

I am trying to develop a pretty big form, I using Nuxt3 and Vee-validation version 4. I am trying to get error from the server but for the limitation of documentation without example and resources in the internet I am having trouble to solve this problem.

```
<template>
<Form @submit="onSubmit" :validation-schema="schema" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <div>
           <label class="input-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
           <input name="first_name" class="input-text" type="text" id="first_name" v-model="form.first_name">
           <ErrorMessage class="text-red-500" name="first_name" />
      </div>
      <div>
           <label class="input-label" for="email">Email</label>
           <input name="email" class="input-text" type="text" id="email" v-model="form.email">
           <ErrorMessage class="text-red-500" name="email" />
      </div>
</Form>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage, useForm } from 'vee-validate';

const schema = {
    first_name: 'required'
    email: 'required'
}
const form = ref<Object>({
    first_name:'',
    email: ''
})
const onSubmit = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/register', {
        method: 'post',
        body: form
    })
    console.log(error.value.data);
}
</script>
```

And here is my server response is look like on console

```
{"email":["This field may not be blank."]}
```

Now how am I supposed to display this on the field of email `ErrorMessage` tag? and how am I supposed to look at errorsBag?

Comment: Check `setFieldError` and `setErrors` for server side validation: https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/composition-api/handling-forms#setting-errors-manually

Answer (score 1):

**I think that you just need to add:**

```
if(form.value) {
            form.value.setErrors(error.value.data);
          }
```

**A complete example is below:**

```
<VForm class="form" ref="form" @submit="submit" :validation-schema="schema" v-slot="{ errors }">
  <div>
    <label class="input-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input name="first_name" class="input-text" type="text" id="first_name" v-model="form.first_name">
    <ErrorMessage class="text-red-500" name="first_name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label class="input-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input name="email" class="input-text" type="text" id="email" v-model="form.email">
    <ErrorMessage class="text-red-500" name="email" />
  </div>
</VForm>

<script lang="ts">
  import { getAssetPath } from "@/core/helpers/assets";
  import { defineComponent, nextTick, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
  import { ErrorMessage, useForm, Field, Form as VForm } from "vee-validate";

  export default defineComponent({
    name: "myForm",
    components: {
      ErrorMessage,
      Field,
      VForm,
    },

    setup() {
      const schema = {
        first_name: 'required',
        email: 'required'
      }

      const form = ref < Object > ({
        first_name: '',
        email: ''
      })
      const onSubmit = async () => {
        const { data, error } = await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/api/accounts/register', {
          method: 'post',
          body: form
        })
        if (form.value) {
          form.value.setErrors(error.value.data);
        }
      }

      return {
        form,
        schema,
        onSubmit
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```